# Breakpoint instruction inside ARM v6 compiler startup code

Tags: stm32, keil, armclang

I am developping a new project for STM32 on Keil MDK 5.28, using ARM compiler V6 (the "new" armclang compiler). It's the first time I'm using armclang.

My reset handler is calling the `__main` symbol. As expected, this is executing some startup code of the Keil C library and then is calling my `main` function (later on, I will remove the calls to the startup code but right now I want to understand the issue).

The problem is the following: there is a BKPT instruction inside one of the C library function (`_sys_open`). I didn't set this breakpoint and it doesn't appear in the breakpoint list. I cannot remove it (tried obviously to rebuild everything). So I cannot start a debug session without breaking at this location.

I also tried to uncheck the option "Run to Main".

[image]

Do you know where this BKPT instruction comes from and how to remove it ?

Comment: Try turning off semi hosting if it is on. I am working with armclang at the moment (porting from armv5 compiler). Its a pain in the backside.

Comment: The breakpoint (`BKPT`) is probably part of some error handler. Find out the corresponding C source line and see what went wrong. Calling `_sys_open` is suspicious anyways...

Comment: Not sure whether that works with µVision/Clang, but with GNU toolchains you could do `addr2line -e YourProgram.elf 0x8000A68` do find the source location of the `BKPT` provided the ELF file contains debugging information.

Comment: According to the map file the instruction is in this function. See screen capture.

Comment: Yes, but not _where_ in that function. There might be something like`if (some error condition) __asm__ volatile ("BKPT");` in  there. You need to find that condition... However, since the `BKPT` appears to be unconditional, it might actually be semihosting-related as Rik said.

Comment: @Erlkoenig BKPT how can it be semihosting related. It breaks always and if the debug hardware is disabled it invokes HF. Pointless to have it in the not currently debugged code. It they left it in the production libraries - it only confirms my opinion about Keil and ARM compiler toolchain :)

Comment: Semihosting is of course supposed to _only_ work with debugger attached, as it is (kind of) a debugging/testing feature. When configured correctly, the debugging software on the PC reacts to the breakpoint, accesses PC resources and places the result in µC memory. It would be _your_ fault for compiling/linking with semihosting-enabled C libraries, or not having it enabled in the debugger configuration.

Comment: @Erlkoenig, apparently you're right, I've found this note in ARM documentation: "Note

ARM processors prior to ARMv7 use the SVC instructions, formerly known as SWI instructions, to make semihosting calls. However, if you are compiling for an ARMv6-M or ARMv7-M, for example a Cortex-M1 or Cortex-M3 processor, semihosting is implemented using the BKPT instruction."

Comment: So it looks semihosting is configured by default ? Do you know how to disable it ?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3614.htm) or [this](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1358938917495.htm) to disable semihosting.

Comment: @Erlkoenig amazing ! Just enabling microlib fixed the issue. It seems like microlib does not use semihosting. I suggest you add an answer to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of the comments:
The breakpoint instruction `BKPT` is part of the semihosting feature, which is supposed to cooperate with the debugger. Enabling Microlib disables semihosting; see [here](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3614.htm) and [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1358938917495.htm).